# Looping through an embedded document that has sub arrays and display them on EJS document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

My goal for this is that i'm trying to loop through an embedded document to display comments for their same id posts.

Here is my Schema structure in node.js server:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    post: String,
    comment: [
        {
        commentname: String,
        comment: String
        }
    ]
});
```

Here is how I receive the add the comments to a post that has the current ID:

```
app.post('/comment/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var comments = {
        commentname: req.body.name,
        comment: req.body.comment
    }
    Posts.update({_id: req.params.id}, {$push: {comment: comments}}, {safe: true, upsert: true}, function(err, comments){

        if (err) {
            console.log("Issue with adding a comment");
            res.redirect('/');
        } else {
            console.log("Success Adding Comments");
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    });
});
```

This is how I am displaying all the post and comments to the main page:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Posts.find({}, function(err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Issue receiving posts');
        } else {
            console.log('Receiving Posts Success');
            res.render("index", {posts: posts});
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what my EJS file looks like:

```
    <% for (index in posts) { %>
    <div class="posts">
        <h3>Name: <%= posts[index].name %></h3>
        <h3>Message: <%= posts[index].post %></h3>
        <div class="comment">
            <h3 class="text-underline"><i>Post a Comment: </i></h3>
            <div class="comments">
                <p>Name: Jimmy</p>
                <p>Comment: I agree, the codingdojo is pretty swell</p>
            </div>
            <div class="comments">
                <p>Name: Bob</p>
                <p>Comment: Why aren't you guys working?</p>
            </div>
            <form action="/comment/<%= posts[index]._id %>" method="post">
                <label for="name" style="display: block">Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                <br />
                <label for="comment">Message: </label>
                <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
                <button class="btn btn-info pull-right">Post Comment</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% } %>
```

I am having trouble figuring out on how to add a nested loop within the post and show the specific comment that belongs to that post.

However I am able to access the name and comment that belongs to the post with the following:

```
<%= console.log(posts[0].comment[0].commentname) %>
<%= console.log(posts[0].comment[0].comment) %>
```

I am very confused on how I am going to add a nested loop within the post in order to display only the comment and name that belongs to that particular post. I currently have dummy text for where the comments are suppose to go also for an example.

*** UPDATE ***

Here is what I have so far:

```
    <% for (index in posts) { %>
    <div class="posts">
        <h3>Name: <%= posts[index].name %></h3>
        <h3>Message: <%= posts[index].post %></h3>
        <div class="comment">
            <h3 class="text-underline"><i>Post a Comment: </i></h3>
        <% if (posts[index].comment != 'undefined') { %>
        <%      for (commentindex in posts[index].comment) { %>
            <div class="comments">
                <p>Name: <%= posts[index].comment[commentindex].commentname %></p>
                <p>Comment: <%= posts[index].comment[commentindex].comment %></p>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% } %>
```

This is printing out the comments at the correct post, which is what I wanted, however now it is printing a lot of undefined out of no where. For example, this is what is on the page:

Name: Victoria
Message: When is lunch arriving?

Post a Comment:

Name: Diana

Comment: Hey, how's it going!?

Name: Robby

Comment: Shut up!

Name: Frankie

Comment: Hey, I need to talk to you!

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Comment: undefined

Name: undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<% for (index in posts) { %>
<div class="posts">
    <h3>Name: <%= posts[index].name %></h3>
    <h3>Message: <%= posts[index].post %></h3>
    <div class="comment">
        <h3 class="text-underline"><i>Post a Comment: </i></h3>
<% for (commentindex in posts[index].comment) { %>
        <div class="comments">
            <p>Name: <%= posts[index].comment[commentindex].commentname %></p>
            <p>Comment: <%= posts[index].comment[commentindex].comment %></p>
        </div>
<% } %>
        <form action="/comment/<%= posts[index]._id %>" method="post">
            <label for="name" style="display: block">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <br />
            <label for="comment">Message: </label>
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-info pull-right">Post Comment</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Here you're able to access the name and the comment that belongs to the post because the loop is inside the posts loop.

Comment: That works, however now, it's printing where the comments are suppose to be at correctly, however now it's printing out a lot of undefined.

Comment: They are datas from your database so you need to do some verifications before adding a comment ( check if they're not null )

Comment: I haven't added any dates to my database, just the name and the comments.

Comment: Or you can do that : `<% for (commentindex in posts[index].comment) { %><% if (posts[index].comment != 'undefined') { %>`

Comment: Yeah, I have done that, it's still spitting out undefined :(

Comment: I meant you just clicked on "Post Comment" without filling your fields so it added empty comments

Comment: I have checked in mongoDB and checked to see if there was any null content, there wasn't any, I put in db.posts.find().pretty(); and there were no null or undefined content because all I had provided is only the name and comment. It also provided the unique id as well.

Comment: So try with `<% if (posts[index].comment[commentindex].commentname != 'undefined') { %>` or `<% if (posts[index].comment[commentindex].comment != 'undefined') { %>`

Comment: It has worked with if(posts[index]).comment[commentindex].comment) itself! Thank you!